# USB Token can't be detected in a docker container

Tags: 18.04, docker, smartcard

I am running a docker image (ubuntu 18.04) with opensc installed. I have an ePass2003 token which works fine on the host (Ubuntu 18.04). I ran the image in privileged mode for test purposes like so:

`docker run --rm -it --privileged mydocker_image:opensc`

and checking `lsusb` outputs:

`Bus 002 Device 005: ID 096e:0807 Feitian Technologies, Inc. ePass2003`

However running `opensc-tool -l` outputs:

`No smart card readers found.`

What can I do to be able to use the usb token from inside the docker container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out, `pcscd service` isn't running! Once I started the service the problem was fixed.